# Passthrough Client Certificate to 3rd party service in Servlet

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, certificate, client-certificates

Assume the following setup:

*Client (sends ClientCert) => Apache SSL => Tomcat => 3rd Party Service (needs Authentication via Client Certificate)*

How can I get the Client Certificate from left to right?
I've tried several things for e.g.
Enabling client certificate check in Apache and give a certificate to Servlet in Tomcat via Apache Header `(RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s")` (but I think that will be only the public part?) and from there via Keystore to 3rd party service. But this one answers with `handshake_failure`, so I assume that certificate will not be sent.

Has anyone a hint or a solution to this problem?